# Seguir escribiendo en la misma linea de un Text aunque ésta supere el ancho del mismo

Tags: python, tkinter

Hola tengo una duda con el widget `Text` de Tkinter y es si hay alguna forma de lograr que al escribir una linea que sea mas larga que el ancho del widget, en vez de cortarse y seguir abajo, siga escribiendo en esa misma linea como sucede con el widget `Entry`.

Este seria un ejemplo:

```
CuadroTexto = Text(frame,font=("Arial", 13), borderwidth=0)
CuadroTexto.pack(fill="both", side="top", expand=True)
```

Comment: Eso mismo es lo que quiero arriba puse lo que use en el widget Text()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por defecto  en un widget `tkinter.Text` se ajusta la longitud de linea para que no supere el ancho del widget, cortando la linea y colocando lo que sobra en la línea siguiente.

Esto se puede cambiar mediante el argumento `wrap` del constructor o posteriormente mediante la opción de ajuste con el mismo nombre (`self.wid_text.config("wrap", valor`)).

Existen tres valores posibles:

- **`"char"/tk.CHAR`**: es el valor por defecto, en este caso se ajusta la línea cortando por cualquier parte de la cadena cuando se supere el ancho del widget.

  ```
  import tkinter as tk


  root = tk.Tk()
  text = tk.Text(root, wrap="char")
  text.pack()
  root.mainloop()
  ```

  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
- **`"word/tk.WORD"`**: el ajuste de linea se produce `preferentemente` en los "saltos de palabra", como los espacios o tabulaciones. Si no hay posibilidad de partir de esta forma (palabra más larga que el ancho del widget) se parte igual que en  el caso anterior.

  ```
  import tkinter as tk


  root = tk.Tk()
  text = tk.Text(root, wrap="word")
  text.pack()
  root.mainloop()
  ```

  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
- **`"none"/tk.NONE`**: no se lleva a cabo ningún ajuste de linea. Esto implica que si el texto supera el ancho del widget parte del mismo no será visible. Podemos movernos y visibilizar el texto usando el cursor o podemos implementar una barra de desplazamiento para facilitar la tarea.

  ```
  import tkinter as tk


  root = tk.Tk()
  text = tk.Text(root, wrap="none")
  text.pack()
  root.mainloop()
  ```

  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

  Añadiendo barras de desplazamiento facilitamos la navegación:

  ```
  import tkinter as tk


  root = tk.Tk()

  xscrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(root, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL)
  yscrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(root)

  text = tk.Text(root, wrap=tk.NONE,
                 xscrollcommand=xscrollbar.set,
                 yscrollcommand=yscrollbar.set)

  xscrollbar.config(command=text.xview)
  yscrollbar.config(command=text.yview)

  yscrollbar.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)
  xscrollbar.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill=tk.X)
  text.pack(expand=tk.TRUE, fill=tk.BOTH)


  root.mainloop()
  ```

Comment: Mil gracias era esto lo que precisaba