# ¿Es posible en tkinter fijar el elemento label de forma determinada para renderiar cadenas de forma lateral solamente?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Llevo desde hace tiempo desarrollando una sencilla app de encriptación en python y me he encontrado con un problema. En un determinado momento, el elemento label(o etiqueta) de salida, llamado 'output', renderiza una serie de cadenas enviadas desde otro script en el formato deseado, sin embargo, el elemento label no puede abarcar la longitud de las cadenas mas largas del código.

La idea es que cuando el dato de salida sea renderizado, y ocupara demasiado espacio, el label mostrara un scroll para mejor visualización.

Me preguntaba si se os ocurre a la comunidad alguna manera de solventar este inconveniente, dado que he tratado todo lo que se me ha ocurrido sin éxito.

Os dejo aquí el código para una mejor comprensión.

```py
import hashlib
import binascii


def hashing_methods(message, iterations):
    # All Hashing methods
    hash_md5 = hashlib.md5(message.encode())
    hash_sha1 = hashlib.sha1(message.encode())
    hash_sha224 = hashlib.sha224(message.encode())
    hash_sha256 = hashlib.sha256(message.encode())
    hash_sha384 = hashlib.sha384(message.encode())
    hash_sha512 = hashlib.sha512(message.encode())

    kd = hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac('sha256', b'password', b'salt', iterations)
    key_deri = binascii.hexlify(kd)

    md5_digest = hash_md5.hexdigest()
    sha1_digest = hash_sha1.hexdigest()
    sha224_digest = hash_sha224.hexdigest()
    sha256_digest = hash_sha256.hexdigest()
    sha384_digest = hash_sha384.hexdigest()
    sha512_digest = hash_sha512.hexdigest()

    # Type = tuple
    output = (" Input:  ", message,
              "\n Output: \nMD5:\n", md5_digest,
              "\n SHA1:\n ", sha1_digest,
              "\n SHA224:\n ", sha224_digest,
              "\n SHA256:\n ", sha256_digest,
              "\n SHA384:\n ", sha384_digest,
              "\n SHA512:\n ", sha512_digest)

    # convert tuple to string
    str_data = ''.join(output)
    # convert key derivation into string
    k_d = key_deri.decode("utf-8")

    result = str_data+"\n key derivation: \n"+k_d

    print(result)

    return result
```

y el codigo de la interfaz grafica

```py
# importing modules
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import simpledialog
from tkinter import StringVar, IntVar
# -----------------------------------------------

# importing scripts
from Hash import hash_method
# -----------------------------------------------
# styles variables
font_app = 'Times'
bg_app = 'gray26'  # '#303F9F'
bg_label = '#FF9800'
fr_app = 'White'
fr_label = 'blue'

ipad_x1 = 200
ipad_x2 = 1
ipad_x3 = 1
ipad_y1 = 50
ipad_y2 = 30
ipad_y3 = 1

# PopupScreen to enter keys


def popupScreen(root):

   answer = simpledialog.askinteger(
       "Key Neccessary", "Enter a key: ", parent=root)
   return answer


def methods(method, value, textlbl, root):

   if method == 'AES':  # if method's button is clicked, it submit a code
       # calling to method's script with our messsage
       var = aes_method.encrypt(value)
       textlbl.set(var)  # update output label's value

   if method == 'ATB':
       var = atbash.Atbash_encrypt(value)
       textlbl.set(var)

   if method == 'BLK':
       # if we need to enter a key, it'll be done by the function
       f = popupScreen(root)
       var = blake.main(value, f)
       textlbl.set(var)

   if method == 'CAESAR':
       g = popupScreen(root)
       var = Caesar.caesar(value, g)
       textlbl.set(var)

   if method == 'FNT':
       var = Fernet.main(value)
       textlbl.set(var)

   if method == 'HSH':
       h = popupScreen(root)
       var = hash_method.hashing_methods(value, h)
       textlbl.set(var)
   if method == 'BNR':
       var = personal.toBinary(value)
       textlbl.set(var)

   if method == 'TRANS':
       f = popupScreen(root)
       var = transmod.encryption(value, f)
       textlbl.set(var, font=(font_app, 2))


# function to reset entry and output values
def resetFunction(text_entry, text_output):
   # set default values to 'entry' and 'output'

   entry_default = ' '
   output_default = 'Data Ouput.'

   # reset values
   text_entry.set(entry_default)
   text_output.set(output_default)

# render function


def gui_frames(root):
   # Label
   label = ttk.Label(root, text='Welcome To CryptoApp', font=(
       font_app, 16), background=bg_label, anchor='center')
   label.pack(fill=tk.BOTH)

   style_entry = ttk.Style()
   style_entry.configure("Frame_entry.TFrame", background=bg_app)
   # Frames
   frame_entry = ttk.Frame(root, style="Frame_entry.TFrame")
   frame_entry.pack(ipadx=ipad_x1, ipady=ipad_y1)

   style_buttns = ttk.Style()
   style_buttns.configure("FrameB.TFrame", background=bg_app)
   frame_matrix = ttk.Frame(root, style='FrameB.TFrame')
   frame_matrix.pack(ipadx=ipad_x2, ipady=ipad_y2)

   # Frame Text(output)
   style_output = ttk.Style()
   style_output.configure("Frame_output.TFrame", background=bg_app)
   frame_output = ttk.Frame(root, style='Frame_output.TFrame')
   frame_output.pack(ipadx=ipad_x3, ipady=ipad_y3)

   # ---------------------------------------------------------------
   label = ttk.Label(frame_entry, text="Insert Text here...",
                     anchor='center', background=bg_app, foreground=bg_label,
                     font=(font_app, 10))
   label.place(x=77, y=50)

   # INPUT
   text_entry = StringVar()
   text_entry.set('')

   entry = ttk.Entry(frame_entry, textvariable=text_entry)
   entry.place(x=180, y=50)
   # ---------------------------------------------------------------
   style_buttons = ttk.Style()
   style_buttons.configure("Style_buttons.TButton")

   # Update label value?
   text_output = StringVar()
   text_output.set('Data Ouput')
   outputlbl = ttk.Label(frame_output, width=10,
                         textvariable=text_output, font=(font_app, 10), anchor='nw')
   outputlbl.pack(ipadx=190, ipady=150)

   # buttons
   aesButton = ttk.Button(frame_matrix, text="AES",
                          command=lambda: methods('AES', entry.get(), text_output, root))

   atbashButton = ttk.Button(frame_matrix, text="Atbash", command=lambda: methods(
       'ATB', entry.get(), text_output, root))

   blakeButton = ttk.Button(frame_matrix, text="Blake", command=lambda: methods(
       'BLK', entry.get(), text_output, root))

   caesarButton = ttk.Button(frame_matrix, text="Caesar",
                             command=lambda: methods('CAESAR', entry.get(), text_output, root))

   fernetButton = ttk.Button(frame_matrix, text="Fernet", command=lambda: methods(
       'FNT', entry.get(), text_output, root))

   hashButton = ttk.Button(frame_matrix, text="Hash", command=lambda: methods(
       'HSH', entry.get(), text_output, root))

   doubleBinButton = ttk.Button(frame_matrix, text="DoubleBin", command=lambda: methods(
       'BNR', entry.get(), text_output, root))

   transpositionButton = ttk.Button(
       frame_matrix, text="Transposition", command=lambda: methods('TRANS', entry.get(), text_output, root))

   button9 = ttk.Button(frame_matrix, text="[Not Avaible]")

   aesButton.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)
   atbashButton.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)
   blakeButton.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=10, pady=10)
   caesarButton.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)
   fernetButton.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)
   hashButton.grid(row=1, column=2, padx=10, pady=10)
   doubleBinButton.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)
   transpositionButton.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)
   button9.grid(row=2, column=2, padx=10, pady=10)
   # ---------------------------------------------------------------

   # Reset Button

   resetButton = tk.Button(root, text='Reset', command=lambda: resetFunction(
       text_entry, text_output), background=bg_label, activeforeground=fr_app, activebackground="blue", height=1, width=10).place(x=20, y=700)

   # Quit Button

   cancelButton = tk.Button(
       root, text='Cancel', command=quit, background=bg_label, activeforeground=fr_app, activebackground="red", height=1, width=10).place(x=400, y=700)

# main function


def main():
   # window creation
   root = tk.Tk()
   # Not Resizable
   root.resizable(False, False)

   # Render at center's screen (aprox.)
   # Gets the requested values of the height and widht.
   winWidth = root.winfo_reqwidth()
   winHeight = root.winfo_reqheight()
   print("Width: {} \nHeight: {}".format(winWidth, winHeight))

   # Gets both half the screen width/height and window width/height
   posRight = int(root.winfo_screenwidth()/2 - (winWidth+500)/2)
   posDown = int(root.winfo_screenheight()/2 - (winHeight+500)/2)
   print("position right: {}, Position down: {}".format(
       posRight, posDown))
   # Positions the window in the center of the page.
   root.geometry("+{}+{}".format(posRight, posDown))

   # giving window's size
   root.minsize(width=500, height=750)
   # rendering at screen's center

   # Window Title
   root.title('CryptoApp')
   # background
   root.configure(bg=bg_app)
   # calling methods
   gui_frames(root)

   root.mainloop()


if __name__ == "__main__":
   main()
```

Comment: En el caso de que eso ocurra ¿Cómo quieres que se comporte el Label?¿Que se muestren barras de scroll si se supera el espacio asignado?

Comment: Esa era la idea. Cuando el dato de salida sea renderizado, y ocupara demasiado espacio, el label mostrara el scroll para mejor visualizacion.

Answer (score 1):

Desgraciadamente, no es posible usar barras de desplazamiento con `tkinter.Label`. No obstante, una solución muy simple pasa por usar `tkinter.Text` en su lugar. Para ello solo debemos tener dos tres cosas en cuenta:

- Crear las scrollbars y configurarlas asociarlas al widget Text.
- Impedir la escritura en el widget, lo cual se puede haacer pasando su estado de `"normal"` a `"disabled"`. Para insertar texto debemos revertir esto temporalmente.
- Evitar que el widget ajuste la longitud de las lineas a su ancho (wrapping):

  [Seguir escribiendo en la misma linea de un Text aunque ésta supere el ancho del mismo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/260336/15089)

Tu código podría quedar así:

```
# importing modules
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import simpledialog
from tkinter import StringVar, IntVar
# -----------------------------------------------

# importing scripts
for Hash import hash_method
# -----------------------------------------------
# styles variables
font_app = 'Times'
bg_app = 'gray26'  # '#303F9F'
bg_label = '#FF9800'
fr_app = 'White'
fr_label = 'blue'

ipad_x1 = 1
ipad_x2 = 1
ipad_x3 = 1
ipad_x4 = 1
ipad_y1 = 50
ipad_y2 = 30
ipad_y3 = 1
ipad_y4 = 30

# PopupScreen to enter keys


def popupScreen(root):

   answer = simpledialog.askinteger(
       "Key Neccessary", "Enter a key: ", parent=root)
   return answer

def update_text(text_widget, text):
   text_widget.configure(state="normal")
   text_widget.delete('1.0', tk.END)
   text_widget.insert('1.0', text)
   text_widget.configure(state="disabled")


def methods(method, value, text_widget, root):

   if method == 'AES':  # if method's button is clicked, it submit a code
       # calling to method's script with our messsage
       var = aes_method.encrypt(value)
       update_text(text_widget, var) 

   elif method == 'ATB':
       var = atbash.Atbash_encrypt(value)
       update_text(text_widget, var) 

   elif method == 'BLK':
       # if we need to enter a key, it'll be done by the function
       f = popupScreen(root)
       var = blake.main(value, f)
       update_text(text_widget, var) 

   elif method == 'CAESAR':
       g = popupScreen(root)
       var = Caesar.caesar(value, g)
       update_text(text_widget, var) 

   elif method == 'FNT':
       var = Fernet.main(value)
       update_text(text_widget, var) 

   elif method == 'HSH':
       h = popupScreen(root)
       var = hash_method.hashing_methods(value, h)
       update_text(text_widget, var) 

   elif method == 'BNR':
       var = personal.toBinary(value)
       update_text(text_widget, var) 

   elif method == 'TRANS':
       f = popupScreen(root)
       var = transmod.encryption(value, f)
       update_text(text_widget, var) 



# function to reset entry and output values
def resetFunction(text_entry, text_output):
   # set default values to 'entry' and 'output'

   entry_default = ' '
   output_default = 'Data Output.'

   # reset values
   text_entry.set(entry_default)
   update_text(text_output, output_default)

# render function


def gui_frames(root):
   # Label
   label = ttk.Label(root, text='Welcome To CryptoApp', font=(
       font_app, 16), background=bg_label, anchor='center')
   label.pack(fill=tk.BOTH)

   style_entry = ttk.Style()
   style_entry.configure("Frame_entry.TFrame", background=bg_app)
   # Frames
   frame_entry = ttk.Frame(root, style="Frame_entry.TFrame")
   frame_entry.pack(ipadx=ipad_x1, ipady=ipad_y1)

   style_buttns = ttk.Style()
   style_buttns.configure("FrameB.TFrame", background=bg_app)
   frame_matrix = ttk.Frame(root, style='FrameB.TFrame')
   frame_matrix.pack(ipadx=ipad_x2, ipady=ipad_y2)

   # Frame Text(output)
   style_output = ttk.Style()
   style_output.configure("Frame_output.TFrame", background=bg_app)
   frame_output = ttk.Frame(root, style='Frame_output.TFrame')
   frame_output.pack(ipadx=ipad_x3, ipady=ipad_y3, padx=10)

   style_cancel = ttk.Style()
   style_cancel.configure("Frame_cancel.TFrame", background=bg_app)
   frame_cancel = ttk.Frame(root, style='Frame_cancel.TFrame')
   frame_cancel.pack(ipadx=ipad_x4, ipady=ipad_y4)

   # ---------------------------------------------------------------
   label = ttk.Label(frame_entry, text="Insert Text here...",
                     anchor='center', background=bg_app, foreground=bg_label,
                     font=(font_app, 10))
   label.pack(side="left")

   # INPUT
   text_entry = StringVar()
   text_entry.set('')

   entry = ttk.Entry(frame_entry, textvariable=text_entry)
   entry.pack(side="left")
   # ---------------------------------------------------------------
   style_buttons = ttk.Style()
   style_buttons.configure("Style_buttons.TButton")

   # Update label value?
   xscrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(frame_output, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL)
   yscrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(frame_output)

   text_output = tk.Text(frame_output,
                         width=10,
                         height=2,
                         font=(font_app, 10),
                         wrap=tk.NONE,
                         xscrollcommand=xscrollbar.set,
                         yscrollcommand=yscrollbar.set)
   text_output.bind("<1>", lambda event: text_output.focus_set())
   xscrollbar.config(command=text_output.xview)
   yscrollbar.config(command=text_output.yview)

   yscrollbar.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)
   xscrollbar.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill=tk.X)
   text_output.pack(expand=tk.TRUE, fill=tk.BOTH, ipadx=190, ipady=150)
   update_text(text_output, "Data Output.")

   # buttons
   aesButton = ttk.Button(frame_matrix, text="AES",
                          command=lambda: methods('AES', entry.get(), text_output, root))

   atbashButton = ttk.Button(frame_matrix, text="Atbash", command=lambda: methods(
       'ATB', entry.get(), text_output, root))

   blakeButton = ttk.Button(frame_matrix, text="Blake", command=lambda: methods(
       'BLK', entry.get(), text_output, root))

   caesarButton = ttk.Button(frame_matrix, text="Caesar",
                             command=lambda: methods('CAESAR', entry.get(), text_output, root))

   fernetButton = ttk.Button(frame_matrix, text="Fernet", command=lambda: methods(
       'FNT', entry.get(), text_output, root))

   hashButton = ttk.Button(frame_matrix, text="Hash", command=lambda: methods(
       'HSH', entry.get(), text_output, root))

   doubleBinButton = ttk.Button(frame_matrix, text="DoubleBin", command=lambda: methods(
       'BNR', entry.get(), text_output, root))

   transpositionButton = ttk.Button(
       frame_matrix, text="Transposition", command=lambda: methods('TRANS', entry.get(), text_output, root))

   button9 = ttk.Button(frame_matrix, text="[Not Avaible]")

   aesButton.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)
   atbashButton.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)
   blakeButton.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=10, pady=10)
   caesarButton.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)
   fernetButton.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)
   hashButton.grid(row=1, column=2, padx=10, pady=10)
   doubleBinButton.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)
   transpositionButton.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)
   button9.grid(row=2, column=2, padx=10, pady=10)
   # ---------------------------------------------------------------

   # Reset Button

   tk.Button(frame_cancel, text='Reset', command=lambda: resetFunction(text_entry, text_output),
      background=bg_label, activeforeground=fr_app, activebackground="blue", height=1, width=10).pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=30)

   # Quit Button
   tk.Button(frame_cancel, text='Cancel', command=quit, background=bg_label, activeforeground=fr_app,
      activebackground="red", height=1, width=10).pack(side=tk.RIGHT, padx=30)


# main function


def main():
   # window creation
   root = tk.Tk()
   # Not Resizable
   root.resizable(False, False)

   # Render at center's screen (aprox.)
   # Gets the requested values of the height and widht.
   winWidth = root.winfo_reqwidth()
   winHeight = root.winfo_reqheight()
   print("Width: {} \nHeight: {}".format(winWidth, winHeight))

   # Gets both half the screen width/height and window width/height
   posRight = int(root.winfo_screenwidth()/2 - (winWidth+500)/2)
   posDown = int(root.winfo_screenheight()/2 - (winHeight+500)/2)
   print("position right: {}, Position down: {}".format(
       posRight, posDown))
   # Positions the window in the center of the page.
   root.geometry("+{}+{}".format(posRight, posDown))

   # giving window's size
   root.minsize(width=500, height=750)
   # rendering at screen's center

   # Window Title
   root.title('CryptoApp')
   # background
   root.configure(bg=bg_app)
   # calling methods
   gui_frames(root)

   root.mainloop()


if __name__ == "__main__":
   main()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]